# Two identical multithreading scripts are causing memoryleak

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine

I am working on my own multithreading for my algorithm independed pathfinding for unity. However, when I am executing two the same class I get a memory leak and when only executing one instance I am having **no** issues. I really want to use at least two threads if it is necessary.

Below is the class I have issues with. Keep in mind, that two independend threads will have to execute parts of this script. `AddJob` can be called from the main unity thread but will most likely be called from another update thread for the agents.

```
namespace Plugins.PathFinding.Threading
{
    internal class PathFindingThread
    {

        private Thread m_Worker;

        private volatile Queue<CompletedProcessingCallback> m_CallbackQueue;
        private volatile Queue<IAlgorithm> m_QueuedTasks;

        internal int GetTaskCount
        {
            get
            {
                return m_QueuedTasks.Count;
            }
        }

        internal PathFindingThread()
        {
            m_Worker = new Thread(Run);
            m_CallbackQueue = new Queue<CompletedProcessingCallback>(); 
            m_QueuedTasks = new Queue<IAlgorithm>();
        }

        private void Run()
        {
            Debug.Log("<b><color=green> [ThreadInfo]:</color></b> PathFinding Thread Started ");
            try
            {
                while(true)
                {
                    if (m_QueuedTasks.Count > 0)
                    {
                        IAlgorithm RunningTask = m_QueuedTasks.Dequeue();
                        RunningTask.FindPath(new IAlgorithmCompleted(AddCallback));
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }

                Debug.Log("<b><color=red> [ThreadInfo]:</color></b> PathFinding Worker is idle and has been Stopped");

            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                Debug.Log("<b><color=red> [ThreadInfo]:</color></b> PathFinding thread encountred an error and has been aborted");
            }
        }

        internal void AddJob(IAlgorithm AlgorithmToRun)
        {
            m_QueuedTasks.Enqueue(AlgorithmToRun);
            //Debug.Log("Added Job To Queue"); 
        }

        private void AddCallback(CompletedProcessingCallback callback)
        {
            m_CallbackQueue.Enqueue(callback);
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if (m_CallbackQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                if (m_CallbackQueue.Peek().m_Callback != null) { }
                    m_CallbackQueue.Peek().m_Callback.Invoke(m_CallbackQueue.Peek().m_Path);
                m_CallbackQueue.Dequeue();
            }

            if (m_Worker.ThreadState != ThreadState.Running && m_QueuedTasks.Count != 0)
            {
                m_Worker = new Thread(Run);
                m_Worker.Start();
            }

        }
    }

    internal delegate void IAlgorithmCompleted(CompletedProcessingCallback callback);

    internal struct CompletedProcessingCallback
    {
        internal volatile FindPathCompleteCallback m_Callback;
        internal volatile List<GridNode> m_Path;
    }
}


namespace Plugins.PathFinding
{
    internal enum TypeOfNode
    {
        Ground,
        Air
    }

    //used to store location information since array can only take rounded numbers
    internal struct Position
    {
        internal int x;
        internal int y;
        internal int z;
    }

    internal class GridNode
    {
        internal Position M_PostitionInGrid { get; private set; }
        internal Vector3 M_PostitionInWorld { get; private set; }

        internal TypeOfNode M_type { get; private set; }

        internal bool m_IsWalkable = true;

        internal GridNode m_ParrentNode;

        internal int Hcost;
        internal int Gcost;

        internal int Fcost { get { return Hcost + Gcost; } }

        internal GridNode(Position postion , Vector3 WorldPosition)
        {
            M_PostitionInGrid = postion;
            m_IsWalkable = true;
            M_PostitionInWorld = WorldPosition;
        }
    }
}
    internal delegate void FindPathCompleteCallback(List<GridNode> Path);

    internal abstract class IAlgorithm
    {
        protected GridNode m_SavedStart;
        protected GridNode m_SavedTarget;

        protected List<GridNode> m_LocatedPath;

        protected FindPathCompleteCallback m_Callback;
        internal FindPathCompleteCallback GetCallback
        {
            get
            {
                return m_Callback;
            }
        }

        protected PathFindingGrid m_grid;

        internal abstract void FindPath(IAlgorithmCompleted callback);

        protected abstract List<GridNode> CreatePath(PathFindingGrid Grid, GridNode Start, GridNode Target);

        protected abstract List<GridNode> RetracePath(GridNode start, GridNode target); 
    }
namespace Plugins.PathFinding.Astar
{

    internal class AstarFinder : IAlgorithm
    {

        //construction of the Algorithm
        internal AstarFinder(GridNode start, GridNode target, FindPathCompleteCallback Callback)
        {
            m_SavedStart = start;
            m_SavedTarget = target;
            m_Callback = Callback;
            m_LocatedPath = new List<GridNode>();
            m_grid = PathFindingGrid.GetInstance;
        }

        //function to start finding a path
        internal override void FindPath(IAlgorithmCompleted callback)
        {

            //running Algorithm and getting the path
            m_LocatedPath = CreatePath(PathFindingGrid.GetInstance, m_SavedStart, m_SavedTarget);

            callback.Invoke(
                new CompletedProcessingCallback()
                {
                    m_Callback = m_Callback,
                    m_Path = m_LocatedPath
                });

        }

        //Algorithm
        protected override List<GridNode> CreatePath(PathFindingGrid Grid, GridNode Start, GridNode Target)
        {
            if(Grid == null ||
                Start == null ||
                Target == null)
            {
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Missing Parameter, might be outside of grid");
                return new List<GridNode>();
            }

            List<GridNode> Path = new List<GridNode>();

            List<GridNode> OpenSet = new List<GridNode>();
            List<GridNode> ClosedSet = new List<GridNode>();

            OpenSet.Add(Start);

            int Retry = 0;

            while (OpenSet.Count > 0)
            {
                if(Retry > 3000 || Grid == null)
                {
                    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Path Inpossible Exiting");
                    break;
                }

                GridNode CurrentNode = OpenSet[0];

                for (int i = 0; i < OpenSet.Count; i++)
                {
                    if(OpenSet[i].Fcost < CurrentNode.Fcost || OpenSet[i].Fcost == CurrentNode.Fcost && OpenSet[i].Hcost < CurrentNode.Hcost)
                    {
                        CurrentNode = OpenSet[i];
                    }
                }

                OpenSet.Remove(CurrentNode);
                ClosedSet.Add(CurrentNode);

                if(CurrentNode == Target)
                {
                    Path = RetracePath(CurrentNode,Start);
                    break;
                }

                GridNode[] neighbour = Grid.GetNeighbouringNodes(CurrentNode);

                for (int i = 0; i < neighbour.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!neighbour[i].m_IsWalkable || ClosedSet.Contains(neighbour[i]))
                        continue;

                    int CostToNeighbour = CurrentNode.Gcost + Grid.GetDistance(CurrentNode, neighbour[i]);

                    if(CostToNeighbour < neighbour[i].Gcost || !OpenSet.Contains(neighbour[i]))
                    {
                        neighbour[i].Gcost = CostToNeighbour;
                        neighbour[i].Hcost = Grid.GetDistance(neighbour[i], Target);
                        neighbour[i].m_ParrentNode = CurrentNode;

                        if (!OpenSet.Contains(neighbour[i]))
                            OpenSet.Add(neighbour[i]);
                    }
                }

                Retry++;
            }
            return Path;
        }

        //retracing the path out of a node map
        protected override List<GridNode> RetracePath(GridNode start, GridNode target)
        {
            List<GridNode> Output = new List<GridNode>();

            GridNode current = start;

            while(current != target)
            {
                Output.Add(current);
                current = current.m_ParrentNode;
            }

            Output.Reverse();

            return Output;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use `ThreadPool` instead of creating new Thread every time?

Comment: Is there a reason for *not* using a blocking queue?

Comment: @Fildor This is Unity3d, `Update` is called once per frame by the engine, even if it is marked as private.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks - totally missed the tag.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it's "causing memoryleak"? Are you seeing an error? If so, please post the full error stack.

Comment: Volatile is for safe access to the field, not the collection itself. That could be your problem. Show us the case with >1 thread and we can see (edit I mesread, this is the case, anyway, the comment on volatile still stands).

Comment: @Programmer Actually i am new to the multithreading world, i didn't know that did exist, thank i will use that in the future.

Comment: @Juan No, i am not seeing an error but my ram increases with about 8 GB's when the 2 instances running.

Comment: How do you know there are only two instances running?

Comment: @Programmer i do have a manager instance on that owns the 2 instances of this class, that class can only have 2 instances. and that manager will make a call to one of the 2 instances to add a job. Would you like to see the manager also ?

Comment: also your Run method could always fail due to the queues always being null

Comment: @mikelegg i am declaring them in the constructor, can you explain ?

Comment: @MarkOostveen - sorry I'm wrong, I forgot you need to call Start before the thread starts. But seriously - volatile is not safe to use like this - you need ot switch to the concurrent queue or put locks in

Comment: You should consider using thread-safe queues (`ConcurrentQueue`).

Comment: Post your `IAlgorithm` class

Comment: @Programmer IAlgorithm  is an abstract class, would you like the class that i am putting into it instead of the abstract one ?

Comment: Both if possible. I really want to make sure nothing else is going on. Also, `FindPathCompleteCallback` and `GridNode` are missing. Since there are many comments and no one can figure out the problem, why not post these missing classes so that someone can try to replicate the issue and figure out what's going on?

Comment: I agree. It almost looks like the source of the problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: Alright, posted. i hope my code doesn't look to bad, first time i am doing something with multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

This shows the core of your code made thread safe.

```
internal class PathFindingThread
    {

        Task m_Worker;

        ConcurrentQueue<CompletedProcessingCallback> m_CallbackQueue;
        ConcurrentQueue<IAlgorithm> m_QueuedTasks;

        internal int GetTaskCount
        {
            get
            {
                return m_QueuedTasks.Count;
            }
        }

        internal PathFindingThread()
        {
            m_CallbackQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<CompletedProcessingCallback>();
            m_QueuedTasks = new ConcurrentQueue<IAlgorithm>();
            m_Worker = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    IAlgorithm head = null;
                    if (m_QueuedTasks.TryDequeue(out head))
                    {
                        head.FindPath(new IAlgorithmCompleted(AddCallback));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Task.Delay(0);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        internal void AddJob(IAlgorithm AlgorithmToRun)
        {
            m_QueuedTasks.Enqueue(AlgorithmToRun);
        }

        private void AddCallback(CompletedProcessingCallback callback)
        {
            m_CallbackQueue.Enqueue(callback);
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            CompletedProcessingCallback cb = null;
            if (m_CallbackQueue.TryDequeue(out cb))
            {
                cb.m_Callback.Invoke(cb.m_Path);
            }
        }
    }
```

Volatile is only good for changing the value of the field - not calling methods on a collection that is referenced by the field.

You propably do not need to have Volatile in CompletedProcessingCallback, but it depends where else this is used. Certainly having volatile on a struct field is a bad smell.

Resolve these thread issues first, then see if you still have the problem.

Comment: I don't think this answer considers a scenario where all jobs have been processed and more are added (after `Run` has completed) which I believe is what the intent of restarting the job in `Update` was (something that caught my eye as the possible source of the problem).

Comment: You are correct - and this looked like a possible cause to me. So with this example code I kept the worker running forever instead.as this easier to be thread safe. It is kind off hard to see the intent - if it does not meet it then I stand corrected.

Comment: Also, you should get rid of the spin-wait. Your CPU will thank you.